# Validate log file using shell

Tags: shell, validation, if-statement, logging, awk

I want to validate a log file based on a reference file, I worked on a script but, it is not beautiful and is not optimal:

For each line I want to check the value of the fields,
 - the field 7 equal to 1 I have to check columns 16 and 17
    - the field 7 equal to 2 I have to check columns 25 and 27 and 30
    - the field 7 equal to 3 I have to check columns 18 and 24 and 31
    etc..

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG=SMS.log



   awk -F\| ' {s=""}
    $4!=0  {printf "API has wrong value"; s="; " }
    $8=="" { printf "%sApplicationID is empty", s; s="; " }
    $9=="" { printf "%shttp request method is empty", s; s="; " }
    $7=="" { printf "%sOperationID is empty", s; s="; " }
    $13 !~ /0|1|2/ {printf "%sresult(0,1,2) has a wrong value", s; s="; " }

        # 1:create SMS

    $7=="1" && $18=="" {printf "%sSender is missing", s; s="; " }
    $7=="1" && $18 ~ /\/tel\:\+\*\*/ {printf "%sSender is cyphred !", s; s="; " }
    $7=="1" && $20=="" {printf "%sAddress is missing", s; s="; " }
    $7=="1" && $20 ~ /\/tel\:\+[0-9]/ {printf "%sAddress(es) is not cyphred", s; s="; " }
    $7=="1" && $10 ~ /\/tel\:\+\*\*/ {printf "%sSender is cyphred on URI !", s; s="; " }

        ## 2:subscribe 

    $7=="2" && $25=="" {printf "%sdestination is missing", s; s="; " }
    $7=="2" && $16=="201" && $27="" {printf "%sresourceId is missing", s; s="; "}

        #3:unsubscribe 
    $7=="2" && $16=="201" && $25="" {printf "%sresource is missing", s; s="; "}

    s { printf "\n"}
    s
     {printf "\n"}
' $LOG
```

Is it possible to update the code to be more optimal and beautiful.
Output:

```
Application is empty; Operation is empty;  Http request method is empty
83ac|EDR|V1|0|V1|2019-05-14|7||||2019-05-14T08:00:42.758Z|8|0|||||XXXXX|||||||||789|||||||||5945548f|||||
```

Comment: You have a couple of `=`s in there that should be `==`, e.g. `...&& $27=""`. Also, should that very bottom `$7=="2"` actually be `$7=="3"` (from reading the `#3:unsubscribe` comment above it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
awk -F'|' '
##### Error Detection
$4 != 0         { prtErr("ApiWrong") }
$8 == ""        { prtErr("AppIdEmpty") }
$9 == ""        { prtErr("HttpEmpty") }
$7 == ""        { prtErr("OpIdEmpty") }
$13 !~ /[012]/  { prtErr("RsltBad") }

$7 == 1 { # 1:create SMS
    if ( $18 == "" )             { prtErr("SndMiss") }
    if ( $18 ~ /\/tel:\+\*\*/ )  { prtErr("SndCyph") }
    if ( $20 == "" )             { prtErr("AddrMiss") }
    if ( $20 ~ /\/tel:\+[0-9]/ ) { prtErr("AddrNotCyph") }
    if ( $10 ~ /\/tel:\+\*\*/ )  { prtErr("SndCyphUri") }
}

$7 == 2 { # 2:subscribe
    if ( $25 == "" )             { prtErr("DestMiss") }
    if ( $16=="201" && $27=="" ) { prtErr("RsrcIdMiss") }
}

$7 == 3 { # 3:unsubscribe
    if ( $16=="201" && $25=="" ) { prtErr("RsrcMiss") }
}

##### Error Reporting
function prtDbg(code,str) { if (doDebug) prtMsg("DEBUG",code,str) }
function prtTrc(code,str) { if (doTrace) prtMsg("TRACE",code,str) }
function prtWrn(code,str) { prtMsg("WARNING",code,str) }
function prtErr(code,str) { prtMsg("ERROR",code,str) }

function prtMsg(level, code, str,       map, msg) {
    map["ApiWrong"]     = "API has wrong value"
    map["AppIdEmpty"]   = "ApplicationID is empty"
    map["HttpEmpty"]    = "http request method is empty"
    map["OpIdEmpty"]    = "OperationID is empty"
    map["RsltBad"]      = "result(0,1,2) has a wrong value"
    map["SndMiss"]      = "Sender is missing"
    map["SndCyph"]      = "Sender is cyphred !"
    map["AddrMiss"]     = "Address is missing"
    map["AddrNotCyph"   = "Address(es) is not cyphred"
    map["SndCyphUri"]   = "Sender is cyphred on URI !"
    map["DestMiss"]     = "destination is missing"
    map["RsrcIdMiss"]   = "resourceId is missing"
    map["RsrcMiss"]     = "resource is missing"
    map["default"]      = "Unknown error code"

    msg = (code in map ? map[code] : map["default"])

    printf "%s: %s[%d]: (%s) %s\n", level, FILENAME, FNR, code, msg | "cat>&2"
    if ( str != "" ) {
        printf "%s: %s[%d]:\t%s\n", $0 | "cat>&2"
    }
}


' "$log"
```

That decouples the text being printed from the error indication and centralizes/instruments all error messages for a common look/feel and ability to add extra info if necessary and to de-clutter the code that's detecting the errors. I also showed how to separate errors, from warnings, etc. (you choose which is which in your code) and add tracing/debugging functions that you can all over the code if you like but to and they won't do anything till you set the relevant "do..." flag on the command line.

---

Update to just produce the specific output you asked for (untested):

```
BEGIN { FS="|" }

##### General processing including error detection
$4 != 0         { logErr("ApiWrong") }
$8 == ""        { logErr("AppIdEmpty") }
$9 == ""        { logErr("HttpEmpty") }
$7 == ""        { logErr("OpIdEmpty") }
$13 !~ /[012]/  { logErr("RsltBad") }

$7 == 1 { # 1:create SMS
    if ( $18 == "" )             { logErr("SndMiss") }
    if ( $18 ~ /\/tel:\+\*\*/ )  { logErr("SndCyph") }
    if ( $20 == "" )             { logErr("AddrMiss") }
    if ( $20 ~ /\/tel:\+[0-9]/ ) { logErr("AddrNotCyph") }
    if ( $10 ~ /\/tel:\+\*\*/ )  { logErr("SndCyphUri") }
}

$7 == 2 { # 2:subscribe
    if ( $25 == "" )             { logErr("DestMiss") }
    if ( $16=="201" && $27=="" ) { logErr("RsrcIdMiss") }
}

$7 == 3 { # 3:unsubscribe
    if ( $16=="201" && $25=="" ) { logErr("RsrcMiss") }
}

{ prtErrs() }

##### Error reporting primitives
function logErr(code) { _errs[code] }

function prtErrs(       code, map, msg, gotErrs, sep) {
    for (code in _errs) {
        gotErrs = 1
        break
    }

    if (gotErrs) {
        map["ApiWrong"]     = "API has wrong value"
        map["AppIdEmpty"]   = "ApplicationID is empty"
        map["HttpEmpty"]    = "http request method is empty"
        map["OpIdEmpty"]    = "OperationID is empty"
        map["RsltBad"]      = "result(0,1,2) has a wrong value"
        map["SndMiss"]      = "Sender is missing"
        map["SndCyph"]      = "Sender is cyphred !"
        map["AddrMiss"]     = "Address is missing"
        map["AddrNotCyph"]  = "Address(es) is not cyphred"
        map["SndCyphUri"]   = "Sender is cyphred on URI !"
        map["DestMiss"]     = "destination is missing"
        map["RsrcIdMiss"]   = "resourceId is missing"
        map["RsrcMiss"]     = "resource is missing"

        printf "%s: %s[%d]: ", "ERROR", FILENAME, FNR  | "cat>&2"
        for (code in _errs) {
            msg = (code in map ? map[code] : "Unknown error code (" code ")")
            printf "%s%s", sep, msg | "cat>&2"
            sep = "; "
        }
        printf "\n%s\n", $0 | "cat>&2"

        delete _errs
    }
}
```

and if you have GNU awk for arrays of arrays and length(array) then I'd do it as:

```
BEGIN { FS="|" }

##### General processing including error detection
$4 != 0         { logErr("Wrong","API") }
$8 == ""        { logErr("Empty","AppId") }
$9 == ""        { logErr("Empty","Http request method") }
$7 == ""        { logErr("Empty","OperationID") }
$13 !~ /[012]/  { logErr("Wrong","Result(0,1,2)") }

$7 == 1 { # 1:create SMS
    if ( $18 == "" )             { logErr("Miss","Sender") }
    if ( $18 ~ /\/tel:\+\*\*/ )  { logErr("Cyph","Sender") }
    if ( $20 == "" )             { logErr("Miss","Address") }
    if ( $20 ~ /\/tel:\+[0-9]/ ) { logErr("NotCyph","Address(es)") }
    if ( $10 ~ /\/tel:\+\*\*/ )  { logErr("UriCyph","Sender") }
}

$7 == 2 { # 2:subscribe
    if ( $25 == "" )             { logErr("Miss","Destination") }
    if ( $16=="201" && $27=="" ) { logErr("Miss","ResourceId") }
}

$7 == 3 { # 3:unsubscribe
    if ( $16=="201" && $25=="" ) { logErr("Miss","Resource") }
}

{ prtErrs() }

##### Error reporting primitives
function logErr(type,item) { _errs[type][item] }

function prtErrs(       map, type, msg, item, sep) {
    if ( length(_errs) ) {
        map["Wrong"]   = "has wrong value"
        map["Empty"]   = "is empty"
        map["Miss"]    = "is missing"
        map["Cyph"]    = "is cyphred !"
        map["NotCyph"] = "is not cyphred"
        map["UriCyph"] = "is cyphred on URI !"

        printf "%s: %s[%d]: ", "ERROR", FILENAME, FNR  | "cat>&2"
        for (type in _errs) {
            msg = (type in map ? map[type] : "Unknown error type (" type ")")
            for (item in _errs[type]) {
                printf "%s%s %s", sep, item, msg  | "cat>&2"
                sep = "; "
            }
        }
        printf "\n%s\n", $0 | "cat>&2"

        delete _errs
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you , how can I print lines that match conditions with error messages using your code , please ?

Comment: Are you asking how to print the input line that each error is about? You can just change `prtErr("SndMiss")` to `prtErr("SndMiss",$0)`, etc. where it's called or modify the `prtMsg()` function to do whatever you want to do for every message or modify `prtErr()` to do anything you want to do for every error but not for all messages, etc.

Comment: note by the way that I changed the name of the variable that contains your log file name from `LOG` to `log` - don't use all upper case variable names for non-exported variables by convention and to avoid clashes with existing variables.

Comment: Did you have any other questions?

Comment: Yes please, I update the code by :function prtMsg(level, code, str,       map, msg, line) and printf "%s: %s[%d]: (%s) %s\n", level, FILENAME, FNR, code, msg, $0 | "cat>&2"     , to got ERROR: edr[2]: (AppIdEmpty)  ApplicationID is empty     ERROR: edr[2]: (OpIdEmpty)  OperationID is empty       98a683eb-4fb7|EDR|V1|0|V1|2019-05-08|7||||2019-05-08T15|24|0||||||||||||||45546F5355||||DeliveryUncertain|||||||||||||||||||||||,      but I just got error message without line :     ERROR: edr[2]: (AppIdEmpty)  ApplicationID is empty     ERROR: edr[2]: (OpIdEmpty)  OperationID is empty

Comment: To change `prtMsg()` to always print the current line all you have to do is add `print | "cat>&2"` before the end of the function. Do exactly that and only that, no need to add parameters to the function or anything else.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I received an error message followed by a line, but is it possible to display for each line all the error messages followed by the corresponding line as follows:
  ERROR: edr [2]: (AppIdEmpty) ApplicationID is empty
  ERROR: edr [2]: (OpIdEmpty) OperationID is empty
  ERROR: edr [2]: (htpREmpty) http request method is empty
98a683eb-4fb7 | BDU | V1 | 0 | V1 | ||||| 2019-05- 2019 | 24 | 0 |||||||||||||| 45546F5355 |||| |||| DeliveryUncertain |||

Comment: You can't put formatted code in a comment so I'm guessing at what you're asking for. Are you asking how to put the current input line on the same line as the error message? To do that you'd just change the `printf` to `printf "%s: %s[%d]: (%s) %s: %s\n", level, FILENAME, FNR, code, msg, $0 | "cat>&2"`

Comment: Thank you but I am asking how to print all error messages followed by the line that match conditions

Comment: Do you **always** want the line printed or only when an error occurs? Is how I formatted the text at the bottom of your question what you're actually looking for for output when those 3 errors occur?

Comment: Mortan I want that when an error or more occurs (ApiWrong, AppIdEmpty, RsltBad, DestMiss...) in the line, then the error messages are printed followed by the line,

Comment: OK if I understand you correctly my updated script should do what you want, please try it. I really wish you'd provided a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output in your question so there wasn't this confusion over your requirements but I should've insisted on that up front before starting trying to answer this, I should know better by now! If what I've posted now doesn't do exactly what you want then please edit your question to provide a [mcve]. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot, your solution is good for my needs :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you could do is get rid of the s variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG=SMS.log

   awk -F\| '
    function add_error(message){
        error = error OFS message
    }

    $4!=0  {add_error("API has wrong value")}
    $8=="" {add_error("ApplicationID is empty")}
    $9=="" {add_error("http request method is empty")}
    $7=="" {add_error("OperationID is empty")}
    $13 !~ /0|1|2/ {add_error("result(0,1,2) has a wrong value")}

        # 1:create SMS

    $7=="1" && $18=="" {add_error("Sender is missing")}
    $7=="1" && $18 ~ /\/tel\:\+\*\*/ {add_error("Sender is cyphred !")}
    $7=="1" && $20=="" {add_error("Address is missing")}
    $7=="1" && $20 ~ /\/tel\:\+[0-9]/ {add_error("Address(es) is not cyphred")}
    $7=="1" && $10 ~ /\/tel\:\+\*\*/ {add_error("Sender is cyphred on URI !")}

        ## 2:subscribe 

    $7=="2" && $25=="" {add_error("destination is missing")}
    $7=="2" && $16=="201" && $27="" {add_error("resourceId is missing")}

        #3:unsubscribe 
    $7=="2" && $16=="201" && $25="" {add_error("resource is missing")}

    {
        print substr(error, length(OFS)+1); #Works even if error is empty
        error = "";
    }

' OFS="; " $LOG
```

I think that it is a bit strange to analyze your log file and create ... a new log file. Why don't you create a csv with 1 column per error and 1/0 values for each line/error ? Your result would be much more easier to analyze and would contains all the informations you need.

Comment: Thank you @Corentin Limier, is it possible print lines that match conditions with error messages ?

Comment: I use the s variable to print line that mach conditions, with error messages

Comment: Output expected :  Application is empty; Operation is empty; Http request method is empty
83ac|EDR|V1|0|V1|2019-05-14|7||||2019-05-14T08:00:42.758Z|8|0|||||XXXXX|||||||||789|||||||||5945548f|||||